# Where and how do particles move?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I've been thinking of making a simple 2d game of some sort involving particles and I've stumbled upon something I haven't really thought about. I know a lot about chemistry, so I'm not new to particles and their behavior, but I realized that I don't know how particles move. What causes them to move, and in what direction to they move. Take water molecules. When water is a liquid, it sticks together due to the polarity of water molecules, but due to the energy and motion of the molecules, it doesn't quite remain as a solid. In the gas state, the energy is even higher allowing the molecules to separate even farther from each other

The final question from all of this is if I were to simulate molecules/particles in a solid, liquid, and gas state, how would I make them move? The inter-molecular attractions are easy enough to code but the motion is what I don't understand. Do they just move randomly all the time, or is there a particular reason why a certain particle would move in a certain direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the simplest of cases where the interaction is only during the collision, you can initiate your particles with random velocities sampled from [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) and random positions.

Then evolve them simply with their respective velocities until they collide, where you can use conservation of energy and momentum to decide new velocities. This is basically kinetic theory of gases.